# Html link click - checking

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to check on the click of a link (html) whether a php session has been set? I am trying to stop a link being clicked should a user not be logged in. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you just hide the link when the user is not logged in and check the session in the backend when someone requests that URL?

Comment: Is the link pointing to your own site or some other site? And why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got your logical sequence of events mixed up. You check the existence of a php session before the page is even served.

Once a link is on the page you cannot directly prevent it from being used, unless you add an on-click listener or handle it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for that. Simply send ajax request to the server and then check if your session is set.